# Docker - Call to backend does not work - even though app/api are on same network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, vue.js

Getting `cors` error when trying to call my backend from frontend, even though apparently network is setup fine.

Pinging from app to api container works as well.

Anything I might be missing?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: 'pg-db'
    image: 'postgres:12'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - smile_network
  web:
    container_name: 'api'
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./api
    image: web:latest
    working_dir: /mnt/rails
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 5050 -b '0.0.0.0' -u puma
    volumes:
      - ./api:/mnt/rails
    ports:
      - '5050:5050'
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - smile_network
  frontend:
    container_name: 'app'
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
      - frontend_node_modules:/frontend/node_modules
    networks:
      - smile_network
volumes:
  db-data:
  frontend_node_modules:
networks:
  smile_network:
    name: smile_network
```

Trying to call `http://localhost:5050/api/v1/` gives me

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5050/api/v1/restaurants' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

running `docker exec -ti app ping api`:

```
PING api (172.20.0.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.20.0.4: seq=0 ttl=64 time=3.850 ms
64 bytes from 172.20.0.4: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.154 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the header (httpd.conf file) to allow from origin 'http://localhost:8080'

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'origin-list'

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Answer (score 0):

I installed `https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors` on my api
and got rid of the error